# Files.Add fails for users with Contribute

Tags: 2010, object-model

I am using the object API to upload files.  In paticular I am doing this..

```
SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(filename, fileStream, author, author, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
```

The problem is that I receive an Access Denied when doing this for a user that has Contribute access.

I have verified that the user does have Contribute access to the list.  I did see mention somewhere else about how this should work if if there is no versioning but we do have versioning enabled so that may be part of the problem?  Not sure..

Comment: If you go to the RootFolder of your list do you have access via the User Interface? What kind o object is "list"? Is it a SPDocumentLibrary?

Comment: The account can access things fine via the User Interface.  And yes, list is a SPDocumentLibrary.

Comment: if you don't mind to save the item with a different user but the System Account you can wrap that code in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // implementation details
});

after the document is added you can modify th Author and Modified attributes

Comment: we very much mind which is why we're trying to resolve this problem.  Not sure why that seems like the default answer everyone gives to everything? :)

Comment: RunWith Rocks! I will try to do a proof of concept trying to reproduce your issue